Why don't countries announce they'll never try to save hostages to discourage the practice?
As an example, let's say Israel announced in 2020 that from now on they won't pay any ransoms, won't trade hostages for prisoners or any kind of favors and won't send in military personnel to save anyone kidnapped. Wouldn't this have significantly diminished the incentive for capturing Israeli hostages from that moment onwards? If you can credibly commit to not care about hostages in the slightest, there's almost no reason to try and capture any.
So why don't countries commit themselves to such a policy?

Don't recent events in Israel show that they still will do all of that for hostages?

Israel hasn't negotiated to free all the hostages in the 2023-24 conflict (to criticism from the families of some hostages), although there seems to have been a softening of their posture since 2014. Here's a 2002 paper on the older Israeli policy, which was to not negotiate or make concessions and instead launch a rapid and forceful military rescue.

@StuartF That doesn't line up with all the news I have been hearing about various agreements and the hostages that have been released so far as part of various deals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Hamas_war_hostage_crisis#:~:text=Holding%20hostages%3A&text=As%20of%2014%20February%202024,Israel%20Defense%20Forces%20(IDF).

First, the title is off.  "Never trade, never pay ransom" makes sense.  "Never save" doesn't.  Successfully rescuing hostages is a deterrent to kidnappers, a serious feather in a government's cap and good outcome to the hostage.
Second, many countries do indeed announce officially, or in frequent communiques, that they won't negotiate with terrorists or criminals.  For exactly the reasons you cite.
In reality, what often happens is that the government states it won't deal, then some time goes by.  The media keeps on talking to relatives and friends of the hostages, who accuse the government of dragging their heels.  Eventually, the hostage gets released and the government basks in public approval, while claiming that they did not deal and offered nothing in return.  The media then turns around and questions how committed the government was to not incentivizing hostage takers, all the more so if some new political development is later visible (release of jailed Russian gun traders (US), promise of referendums in New Caledonia (France)).
Democratic governments exist in symbiosis with their electorates.  Those electorates generally do not favor "leaving a man behind".  So there's a delicate balance between not incentivizing and appearing heartless and incompetent for years on end as the hostages' plight stays in the media.
The game theory decision matrix on the hostage takers' end is complex as well.  "You don't negotiate?  We kill hostages!"  leaves you with no bargaining chip and with a government that might very well be out for revenge to appear competent.  Yet, keeping hostages captive for years is a drain on resources and eventually might result in a rescue raid.
One mode of operation, in certain countries, is to mount rescues that are so bloody-minded and careless with hostage lives that hostage takers are aware that there is limited space to bargain with (opera rescues with fentanyl gas, shooting tanks and heavy rockets at schools).  If the rescue succeeds, great.  If it doesn't, find a scapegoat, but you've still signaled not to mess with you because you're a manly man who doesn't care much.
This tendency to speak tough - "no negotiation!" but then in actuality privilege just that is what allowed 9/11 to happen *.  At the time - and it was a rational expectation - the standard response to air highjackings was to calm things down, negotiate and save the hostages.  Despite decades of experience with hijackers that had become more or less official policy.  And probably for good reasons.
Ditto with Israel, which despite more experience with terrorist and hostage takers than most nations ought to be asked to bear, operates on a mix of retribution, no negotiation and... quietly releasing prisoners.
In short, a policy of never dealing is a hard sell for most democracies.  But an easier one for autocracies.  You deal, but you try to make it unattractive to hostage takers by not being a pushover and you try to take the terrorists out whenever possible.
And, sometimes, negotiating is what is for the best anyway, because some give and take is actually good for the wider peace.  Had the British government stuck to their official script - "we don't deal with terrorists!" - then the Good Friday Agreements would have never happened.
* Post-9/11 airliner hijackings seem to have fairly much fallen off the radar, not unlike what this solution's proponents seem to envision.  That is because people are terrified of possible outcomes so passengers would presumably react violently, even if at great risk.  There is no "dealing-with-hijackers" like there was pre-9/11.  On the flip side, seems like the bad guys are fonder of just indiscriminate killings so not sure things have improved that much.  And it took mass deaths to get there as well.

Excellent point re: Russia's handling of hostage situations. Seems like they de facto do this already.

They do.  The UK, for example:

The UK's position on payment of terrorist ransoms is very clear: we do not pay, on the basis that providing money or property to a terrorist group fuels terrorist activity; and encourages further kidnaps. Payment of terrorist ransoms is illegal under the Terrorism Act 2000 – and this has extra-territorial effect.

This is the also the stated policy of G8 members, and Security Council resolution 2133 calls all member states to prevent terrorists from benefiting directly or indirectly from ransom payments or political concessions.
But sending in the army to rescue hostages is the opposite thing.  It normally results in the terrorists getting killed, which is not to their advantage.
It's just not credible to believe that do "not care in the slightest" about your citizens (and voters, and taxpayers), when you are running a government that is doing things like providing health, education, security and infrastructure to those citizens.

I think even among G8 members the situation is more complicated. Some like the UK and the US have an official 'we don't pay' policy. But I think France does negotiate and the UK did in the past during the Northern Ireland conflict. I don't think there are enough cases to make a statistical argument on whether the policy works in reducing kidnappings.

When a rescue goes well, it can be effective in influencing a wider conflict. Operation Barras is about as successful as they come.

Terrorism is a type of psychological warfare. It uses random, public, and largely symbolic acts of violence not merely to produce fear, but to promoted anger and distrust among citizens against their government. The goal is to get average citizens to start fuming that the government isn't protecting them and their loved ones, and to start wondering why average citizens like them are suffering because of governmental policies or actions that only seem to benefit the rich and powerful. That's why terrorism is so difficult to address:

If a government steadfastly refuses to do anything at all for hostages, it sows distrust and resentment among citizens, which is what terrorists want
If a government overreacts and uses heavy force, it reaffirms the terrorists' message that the government is being brutal in ways that don't serve the interests of average citizens, which is what terrorists want
If a government hems and haws, looking weak and confused, citizens start losing faith in it, which is what terrorists want

There are effective ways of dealing with this kind of psychological warfare, but they are difficult to execute in the best of circumstances, and unappealing to the typical political mindset. For politicians, an act of terrorism against their citizens is both a tragedy and an opportunity to demonstrate their leadership and mettle. This often creates a unhealthy dynamic in which average citizens are caught between terrorists and extremist politicians, both of whom want to leverage citizens' existential fear to obtain power.

Because human lives matter ... because humanity matter
The pointed solution can be further continued with no limit. What if we kill our own innocent people to show our enemies we are not afraid of our people being killed, so that they will stop trying to attack us and kill the innocents? Maybe you have watched the movie the usual suspects wherein:

According to Kint, Söze began his criminal career as a small-time drug
dealer. Horrifically though, one afternoon while Söze is away from
home rival Hungarian gangsters attempt to intimidate him by taking his
family hostage and raping his wife, then when he returns home,
slitting the throat of one of his children right before his eyes.
Determined to show these men of will, what will really was, Söze
shoots and kills his own family and all but one of the Hungarians,
letting the last leave so he can tell his cohorts what happened. Once
his family is buried, Söze massacres the Hungarian Mafia, their
families, their friends, and even people who owe them money. 
[wikipedia]

When morals are just tools to play with, and to make politics, all these can happen ... When Human lives matter only because people are voters/tax payers, again such acts are thinkable ... When morality is a set of mere words, this sort of decision making can continue as much as voters/tax payers can bear, not rebelling against the politicians ...

+1 for the Usual Suspects reference, this is exactly what I was thinking of when writing the question.


Wouldn't this have significantly diminished the incentive for capturing Israeli hostages from that moment onwards? If you can credibly commit to not care about hostages in the slightest, there's almost no reason to try and capture any.

Not really. Something a lot of folks in Western countries seem to always miss is that there are other reasons to take hostages beyond ransoms. Boko Haram, for instance, is a militant Islamic separatist group in Nigeria. In 2014, they kidnapped 276 schoolgirls. Their reasons were partially ethnic

The children’s abduction is not driven by the need for ransoms and such abductions can only be resolved through negotiations with the armed groups, according to Sheikh Ahmad Gumi, a Nigerian cleric known to have access to the bandits and who has negotiated with them in the past.
“It is more than an economic motive,” Gumi said, saying there is “an underground ethnic war” between the the herdsmen from the Fulani ethnic group and other, more urbanized parts of Nigeria. His comments echoed claims made previously by the herdsmen that they struggle with less development than other regions.

This is the same problem Israel faces. Even with a hard-line no-negotiation stance, you're going to have groups like Hamas, whose goals are partially rooted in religion and ethnic strife.
Other reasons to seize hostages without a ransom demand could include sex trafficking and slavery. Ransoms are merely the most common reason to take hostages.

In Germany, the "do not negotiate" doctrine has even been discussed before the Bundesverfassungsgericht (Constitutional Court).
In 1977, leftist terrorists kidnapped the industrialist Hanns-Martin Schleyer and demanded the release of their comrades from prison.
In the case of the 1975 kidnapping of Peter Lorenz the German government had decided to accept an exchange, but had come to the conclusion that had been an error, as the freed terrorists immediately rejoined their group and took part in further violent action.
Now, in the case of Schleyer, and other kidnappings in the same year, the government and Chancellor Schmidt very publicly anounced that they would not negotiate with terrorists. The son of Hanns-Martin Schleyer filed a suit before the Constitutional Court asking for a review of the policy and demanding that his father's life should be saved by releasing the imprisoned terrorists. This was rejected by the court in a Judgment of 16 October 1977 (German original). It cited a statement by the Federal Minister of Justice:

Einerseits gehe es darum, alles Menschenmögliche zu tun, um das Leben des Antragstellers zu schützen. Auf der anderen Seite werde aber mit dem Eingehen auf die Forderungen der Entführer das Leben weiterer Unbeteiligter in höchstem Maße gefährdet; denn die elf inhaftierten Terroristen seien besonders gefährlich. Nach ihrer Freilassung würden sie, wie die Erfahrungen nach dem Entführungsfall Lorenz gezeigt hätten, ihr verbrecherisches Tun fortsetzen...Ihre Erfüllung würde den Staat um die Fähigkeit bringen, Schutz zu gewähren.

(This paragraph is not part of the official translation, therefore here it is presented with the help of DeepL.com)

On the one hand, it was a matter of doing everything humanly possible to protect the applicant's life. On the other hand, the lives of other innocent people would be jeopardised to the highest degree if the kidnappers' demands were met, as the eleven imprisoned terrorists were particularly dangerous. After their release, they would continue their criminal activities, as the experiences after the Lorenz kidnapping case had shown... Their fulfilment would deprive the state of its ability to provide protection.

and came to the conclusion the court must not intervene, as the government should have the freedom to decide its own strategy:
(official translation)

The state organs are, as a matter of principle, responsible themselves for determining how to fulfil their duty to effectively protect life. They decide what protective measures are to the purpose and necessary to ensure that life is effectively protected...
The particularity of the protection against terrorist ransom demands with death threats is the need to adapt the necessary measures to a wealth of singular situations. General norms governing such measures cannot be laid down in advance, nor can norms be derived from an individual fundamental right. The Basic Law not only gives rise to a duty to protect individuals, but also to protect all citizens as a group. To discharge this duty effectively, the competent state organs must be in a position to respond appropriately to the circumstances of the specific case; this alone precludes any advance determination of the means available. Furthermore, such determination cannot be made under constitutional law, because it would mean, in particular, that terrorists would be able to predict the state’s response. That would make it impossible for the state to protect its citizens. This would be an irresolvable obstacle to the task entrusted to it under Art. 2(2) first sentence GG.


Nice reference. Any idea how consistently has Germany followed this policy?

@sfxedit I think the official policy has latched on more on to the courts conclusion that "any advance determination of the means available...cannot be made". So most of the time in recent decades the government speakers commented to inquiries with either asserting it would not pay ransom, or with a terse "no comment". And a law stating the policy, as cited in another answer for the UK, would be precluded by this decision.

The "no comments" are always interesting to follow-up because it does suggest that the government considered not following the policy.

There is a difference in publicly proclaiming "we don't negotiate with terrorists" vs "we don't care about the hostages, do whatever you want with them".
The former is more palatable with the voters because most of the population (especially those not directly impacted by the kidnapping) will find it rationally reasonable enough, as there is some expectation of government action against the terrorists. But the latter creates an impression in the voters that the government not only doesn't care about its people, but is also abstaining from its responsibility to them (to safeguard its citizens). Imagine if the government says we won't do anything to save the hostages and then the terrorists brutally kill them (remember ISIS broadcasting videos of beheading?) - public outrage in such cases will also rightly be targeted at the government too because it creates a feeling of insecurity amongst the voters (which is what terrorism is all about).
Add to this the fact that whenever a terrorist incident happens, the government is also rightly blamed for failing to protect its people and provide them adequate security from such violence. So a government that is seen to fail to take actions when terrorist incidents happen, will soon become highly unpopular.
Israel's anti-terrorism policy has been that if the "price" is not too high, it will give in to the terrorists and get any hostages back. But it will never give up hunting for them. But, if the demands of the terrorists are seen to be "unreasonable", Israel is willing to let the hostages die - either while rescuing them or by the terrorists. (And later hunt for the terrorists).
In the recent incident of Hamas attack and kidnapping, the reason why we don't see Israel applying this policy consistently is because Hamas had also kidnapped foreigners. And for diplomatic reasons, Israel had to comply with the wishes of the foreign governments to get back their citizens safely. Netanyahu used this opportunity to get back some of the Israeli hostages too and salvage some political points with his voters. But once that was done, Netanyahu and his war council applied Israel's anti-terrorist policy with a brutal purpose (‘Hostages Weren’t Our Top Priority’: How Israel’s Bombing Frenzy Endangered Captives in Gaza), and stopped caring about Hamas' demands or the hostages - most of the Israeli hostages so far have been killed in IDF bombing only. (This is known as the Hannibal doctrine, which now applies even to civilian terrorist hostage situations on a case by case basis, applied in combination with the Dahiya doctrine).
Note that the Israelis hold Netanyahu responsible for the security failure that allowed this terrorist incident to happen, and he is thus under tremendous pressure from the voters - so even he has had to use all his political ingenuity and propaganda to stop Israelis from focusing on the dead hostages and keep inflaming their hatred to keep them obsessed on the ever increasing count of dead Palestinians as "proof" of his "victory" against Hamas. Meanwhile, to salvage his political reputation for posterity, he has also been using the opportunity to do even more land grab from the Palestinians in both West Bank and Gaza - we'll have to wait and see if Israelis will be happy enough with that to overlook all the dead hostages - the point being that ultimately it is all about perception with the voters, and the actual anti-terrorist policy doesn't really matter if the voters can be placated to support you again.

Imagine if the government says we won't do anything to save the hostages => they could still retaliate in kind. I.e. Israel targets a 1:100 ratio of deaths on their side vs the Palestinian side, hence the Gaza war is unlikely to end before ~140k Palestinians are dead. Just not allow the other side to use hostages as any sort of leverage.

@JonathanReez True. But then, consider that both Israel and Palestine have been facing terrorism from each other for decades now. At some point, revenge killings just tire out the population. That's true of Palestine too - the rise of Hamas is also because the Palestinians started losing hope with PLAs policies, and looked for alternatives. Ultimately, revenge killings only provide short-term political advantage. But in the long term, as terrorist violence continues, or even escalate, people just get fed up with it and ask why the government isn't competent enough to provide them peace?

@JonathanReez And let's face it - society in general is more forgiving to government ransoming hostages than seeing some member of their society dead (even if their death is avenged). Ultimately we humans formed societies to protect ourselves - most of thus will empathetically identify with the family of a dead hostage because we too love someone and would hate to lose them to some senseless violence.

To be fair, Israel did strongly consider simply expelling the Gazans into Egypt and there was a non-zero chance of it succeeding as a strategy. It's plausible that eventually the violence will reach a point where Israel will be ready to bite the bullet and just expel everyone from "Greater Israel". So escalations in violence can solve the problem, as long as neither side is willing to stop at the next spiral.

@JonathanReez, please provide official statements for "consider" ,and not some far right extremists claims
